# Future of OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

Since CallidusCloud Acquired OrientDB, does anyone knows about its future? 
The [announcement](http://orientdb.com/calliduscloud-acquires-orientdb-the-leading-multi-model-database-technology/) says...

> "CallidusCloud will continue to enhance the technology, expand the
>   customer base, and support the OrientDB open source community."

It's good to see that community version will be supported. But will it be under Apache 2 License?

Comment: This is not the right forum for this question. I'm not sure which SE site to suggest. You should read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you are unsure about what types of question are in scope for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, OrientDB Community Edition remains Open Source with Apache 2 license (Open Source).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering will OrientDB (community) follow the fate of Titan. Looks not :)